# Express: Sending POST request from React frontend sends in an empty body, but sending from Postman sends the body correctly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, post, postman

I am making a web app with a React frontend and a Node Express backend. When I send a POST request with a JSON body to one of my endpoints, and print the contents of req.body from the server, I get an empty object. However, when I send the exact same request from Postman, it works perfectly.

In the "network" tab of developer tools, I see this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyNum.png). The payload of the request seems to be correct.

Here is my frontend request code:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/building', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({buildingAttempt: 'test'}),
    }).then(function (res) {
      // deal with result
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }).finally(function () {
    });
```

On the backend, I print the contents of req.body to test:

```
app.use('/building', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  
  // other code
}
```

I've already tried including the code snippet below to deal with origin issues:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

I've also added the json body parser:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Postman is not a browser, and does not perform the universal [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) that browsers perform, so it's a good bet you forgot to allow the http `OPTIONS` verb, and the browser never even gets to send a POST. Open your dev tools, go to the "network" tab, and look at what happens when you try that `fetch` call: which network requests are sent, with which headers, and which payloads, and what are their server responses? (and of course: make sure to put those details in your post, because they matter a lot)

Comment: Thanks! On the network tab, it says that the status of the request is "(failed)net::ERR_FAILED". The payload seems to be correct, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using cors i think

1. npm install cors
2. import cors on the server
3. app.use(cors())

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use axios?? its way easier for you.

create a services folder, and inside it an api.js file

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const api = axios.create({

baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'

})
```

```
//file where you're making the request
import api from '...path...'

api.post('/building', { test: 'test data' })
```

Comment: try this and tell me what happens

Comment: The body object is still empty.

Comment: remove the '/' from buildings and check if the path is correct

Comment: Also, can you show the code, or something that will help visualize the problem??